# Взаимодействие аудио и видео

Tags: javascript, html

Имеется такой простой код(*как для примера*):

```
<video src="video.mp4" class="play" onplay="clickPause([0])"></video>
<audio src="music.mp3" class="play" onplay="clickPause([1])"></audio>

<script>
    // Pause / play
    let a = document.getElementsByClassName("play");

    function clickPause(b) {
        for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (!(i == b)) { a[i].pause(); a[i].currentTime = 0; };
        }
    }

</script>
```

Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на 'аудио' останавливалось 'видео' и наоборот? Пробовал JS кодом в примере выше не помогло(хотя делал для аудио, и всё было норм).

**Возможно я не так правильно гуглил или 'как долго'. Думаю смысл кидать ссылку на песочницу, типа codepen нет**

Comment: А таких элементов только два на странице? То есть.. видео одно и аудио одно?

Comment: На данном примере - да, только два.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<video src="video.mp4" class="play" onplay="clickPause(1)"></video>
<audio src="music.mp3" class="play" onplay="clickPause(0)"></audio>
<script>
 // Pause / play
let a = document.getElementsByClassName("play");
function clickPause(b) {
    a[b].pause(); 
    a[b].currentTime = 0;
}
</script>
```